# How to flutter sdk upgrade in specific version

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to upgrade flutter specific version. How to do , i don't want to upgrade latest sdk version. I want tp upgrade specific sdk version

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue about your question on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14230). I think it is not possible yet.